# How to intilize link using queryselector

Tags: java, jquery

I want to click second link

```
<ul id="library_list" class="side-menu" style="height: 358px;">
    <li class="side-menu-section selected-section">
        <a class="side-menu-section-link qa-group-id-undefined open" href="#">First Link</a>
    </li>
       <li class="side-menu-section">
            <a class="side-menu-section-link qa-group-id-undefined" href="#">Second Link</a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

I got exception by executing  the following code

```
pageUrls.QuerySelector('side-menu-section a[text="SecondLink"]')).Click()
```

Can you please help out from this issue.

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: Do you mean "querySelector" in JavaScript?

Comment: im using queryselector method in Test complete tool(Automation testing tool). im getting objects by CSS selector..i need to click on Second link.i got pageUrls.QuerySelector(...)' is null or not an object.

Comment: Is this correct  'side-menu-section a[text="SecondLink"]' which i mentioned in queryselector?

Comment: since (.side-menu-section) is an array of element so you would haveto select the exact index for (.side-menu-section) and then you should select (a[text="SecondLink"]) inside that index. let me know if that does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your selctor is not correct...

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.side-menu-section:last-child a'));
```

```html
<ul id="library_list" class="side-menu" style="height: 358px;">
    <li class="side-menu-section selected-section">
        <a class="side-menu-section-link qa-group-id-undefined open" href="#">First Link</a>
    </li>
       <li class="side-menu-section">
            <a class="side-menu-section-link qa-group-id-undefined" href="#">Second Link</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: np, glad I could help!